# Improve Performance With GDI+

Tags: vb.net, bitmap, gdi+, gdi

As a challenge, I am planning to make a game purely in Visual Studio (using Visual Basic) but in the past, I have noted that GDI+ is not the best rendering tool, but for what it is, it's all right.

What settings should I use and not use when working with GDI+? Here are my assumptions:

- `InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor` It would make sense that this option renders the fastest.

  `PixelOffsetMode = Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.Half` This seems like it must be used with NearestNeighbor.

  `CompositingQuality = ?` I am not sure about this one.

  `CompositingMode = ?` Again, I can't tell.

  `SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.None` Specifying no smoothing mode would probably run the fastest.

  `SetClip(ClientRectangle)` It would make sense to set this as the clip so the graphics would not draw outside of the form or control.

My next point: I've noticed that adding all the graphics code always works the fastest in `Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs)` Is there any benefit to doing something like this inside that void: (Creating a temporary bitmap and drawing it onto the screen.)

```
    Using B As New Bitmap(ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height, Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb)
        Using G As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(B)
            ' Draw objects onto the bitmap.
        End Using
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(B, 0, 0)
    End Using
```

I ask this because I noticed that when creating a bitmap, you can specify a `Imaging.PixelFormat`. Is there one type of format that renders faster than the rest?

Thank you all in advance for the help.

*~Nic*

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use a gaming kit such as XNA or Monogame ...

Comment: I believe `32bppPArgb` has proven to be quite fast (the _**P**_ means that it uses _**premultiplied**_ alpha).